# How to send tradingview alert with updated plot values when alerting long/short positions

Tags: pine-script

I have an alert that pulls information from my strategy code to determine my market position, positon size and take profit percentage.

{{strategy.market_position}} SOLUSDT q={{plot_10}} tp={{plot_9}}% Hedge

I am having issues with{{plot_10}} and {{plot_9}} values being taken from the bar prior to the {{strategy.market_position}} change.

For example, if there is an alert for a long position then position size and take profit percentage is taken from the bar prior to the long position being opened.

I need to take the plot values immediately after the position is opened, not before.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want no delay, then you need to use your long/short condition to change the values you want.

Some thing like this:

```
// Update stop loss price if you are not already in a long position and your long condition is true
if ((strategy.position_size <= 0) and (your_long_condition))
    StopLossPrice :=longStopPrice
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My question wasn't described very well. I have now edited it to provide more detail.